# Memory management when to use release

Tags: ios, memory-management

I had another question about memory management in iOS 3.0+, I know if we did [varialbe release] will release its retain to an object, but code like this -

```
- (void) getPostsFromJson:(NSData *)data
{
    NSError *theError = nil;

    NSDictionary *dict = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:data error:&theError];

    if (dict == nil) {

        [SystemStatusValues getInstance].isValidJson = NO;
        [SystemStatusValues getInstance].httpStatus = HTTP_STATUS_FAILED;

        NSLog(@"getPostsFromJson - %@ %@",
              [theError localizedDescription],
              [[theError userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    } else {

        NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];        
        keys = [keys sortedArrayUsingFunction:keySortByInteger context:nil];

        self.keys = keys;
        self.posts = dict;
        NSLog(@"Posts : getPostsFromJson = %@", self.posts);

        if ([keys count] < TOTAL_SECTIONS) {

            [SystemStatusValues getInstance].isValidJson = NO;

        } else {

            [SystemStatusValues getInstance].isValidJson = YES;
            if (self.nextPosts == nil) {

            }

        }

        // [keys release];
        // [dict release];
        return;
    }
}
```

You can see there are two local variables - keys and dict, did I need to call [keys release] or [dict release] at the end of code? Actually I did it, but it brings crushing sometimes. So for local variables, we don't need to release it after it's used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both dict and keys are reference to autoreleased objects. You shouldn't release them, which will cause your program to terminate. `You Don’t Own Objects Returned by Reference and You must not relinquish ownership of an object you do not own`

*So for local variables, we don't need to release it after it's used?* If you own the objects you must release them when you no longer need them, doesn't matter if its local variable or ivar.

Read this - [Advanced Memory Management Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

[It's simple](http://whentouseretaincount.com/):

> If you alloc, copy or retain an object
>   you need to release it. Otherwise you don’t.

So you don't need to release either keys or dict (they're both autoreleased).

Answer (score 0):

Don't release `keys` array. Because `allKeys` method probably returns autoreleased `NSArray` object. So it will be released later by system.

It seems like `deserializeAsDictionary` also returns an autoreleased `NSDictionary`, so you shouldn't release it too.

Release objects only created with `alloc`. In this case, you're using external methods. You need to follow that methods, and see if that object are created with alloc.

Comment: You can relinquish ownership for objects created using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”.